# Why appear "Linux host path" in the process of the code "echo"? Usage PHP extension "PCNTL"

Tags: php, linux, php-extension, pcntl

I use PHP extension "PCNTL" write some codes, and run it in terminal, but why appear the Linux host Path 
`"gdy@localhost:~/myDev/webroot/spider/my$"`

[This is my echo in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnT3Y.jpg)

[This is my PHP CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9MLb.jpg)

Comment: Please upload the picture of the code as actual code.

Comment: … which means: upload your code not as a picture, but as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why appear the Linux host Path 
>   `"gdy@localhost:~/myDev/webroot/spider/my$"`

This is simply the prompt of your shell, which naturally appears because the parent process in your PHP CODE has run to its end. And this is because you used [`pcntl_waitpid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-waitpid.php)'s ***WNOHANG*** option.